tried running a powshell script told running scripts is disabled on
I created a simple PowerShell script that is a .ps1 file extension. I tried running it and I.\hello.ps1 :

File C:\Users\JohnZalubski\desktop\hello.ps1 cannot be loaded because
running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see
about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:1

.\hello.ps1

  + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess got the compile error of




Is there anyway around this?
I thought I could run the script without admin privileges.

Did you follow the advice in the error message?
